How to Implement Full Bundle Adjustment for Multi-Camera Extrinsic Calibration with Ceres Solver?
I want to implement a bundle adjustment in Ceres Solver. Here is my understanding of the implementation steps:

Define the Reprojection Error:
struct ReprojectionError {
    ReprojectionError(double observed_x, double observed_y, const cv::Mat& K)
        : observed_x(observed_x), observed_y(observed_y), K(K) {}

    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T* const extrinsics, const T* const point, T* residuals) const {
        // Unpack extrinsics
        const T* rotation = extrinsics;
        const T* translation = extrinsics + 3;

        // Project the 3D point to 2D
        T p[3];
        ceres::AngleAxisRotatePoint(rotation, point, p);
        p[0] += translation[0];
        p[1] += translation[1];
        p[2] += translation[2];

        // Apply the intrinsic matrix
        T xp = p[0] / p[2];
        T yp = p[1] / p[2];

        // Convert to image plane
        T u_proj_x = T(K.at<double>(0, 0)) * xp + T(K.at<double>(0, 2));
        T u_proj_y = T(K.at<double>(1, 1)) * yp + T(K.at<double>(1, 2));

        // Compute the residuals
        residuals[0] = u_proj_x - T(observed_x);
        residuals[1] = u_proj_y - T(observed_y);

        return true;
    }

    static ceres::CostFunction* Create(double observed_x, double observed_y, const cv::Mat& K) {
        return (new ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<ReprojectionError, 2, 6, 3>(
            new ReprojectionError(observed_x, observed_y, K)));
    }

    double observed_x;
    double observed_y;
    cv::Mat K;
};


Add Observations to the Problem:
ceres::Problem problem;
for (const auto& observation : observations) {
    ceres::CostFunction* cost_function =
        ReprojectionError::Create(observation.x, observation.y, intrinsics[observation.camera_id]);
    problem.AddResidualBlock(cost_function,
                             nullptr,
                             extrinsics[observation.camera_id],
                             points_3d[observation.tag_id]);
}


Run the Solver:
ceres::Solver::Options options;
options.linear_solver_type = ceres::DENSE_SCHUR;
ceres::Solver::Summary summary;
ceres::Solve(options, &problem, &summary);
std::cout << summary.FullReport() << "\n";



Am I correctly implementing the bundle adjustment correctly?
